# Stop Duplicate title in front end post form using Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, duplicates, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using Gravity Forms for front-end post publishing. Now I want to stop duplicate title in frontend. Please tell me about it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in function php

```
$page_check = get_page_by_title($content['title'], OBJECT, 'post'); 
if(!$page_check->ID){ 
    //do something when post not exits 
}else{ 
    // give a error or something
}
```